# How do I define an XSLT test that verifies the presence of an element in descendants?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to correct an existing XSLT test that is reporting a false positive.

This is the current XSLT test logic (the complete XSLT template has been omitted for brevity:

```
<xsl:template match="/atom:feed/atom:entry[*/espi:IntervalBlock]" priority="4000" mode="M10">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="atom:content/espi:IntervalBlock/espi:IntervalReading/espi:value" />
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <assert TestID="EU_FB04_DE_027">
                <role></role>
                <TestName>IntervalReading value</TestName>
                <Report>verify the presence of a valid value</Report>
                <diagnostics>for future use</diagnostics>
            </assert>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()" mode="M10" />
</xsl:template>
```

This is a sample of an XML file that should fail the test (simplified for brevity), but is passing the above test:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:espi="http://naesb.org/espi"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://naesb.org/espi ../SchemaFiles/usage.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <entry>
        <id>urn:uuid:81ED3A7C-AF13-4632-AD63-5A2565EE20A3</id>        <title/>
        <content>
            <IntervalBlock xmlns="http://naesb.org/espi">
                <IntervalReading>
                    <cost>8236</cost>
                    <timePeriod>
                        <duration>3600</duration>
                        <start>1333252800</start>
                        <!-- 4/1/2012 4:00:00 AM  -->
                    </timePeriod>
                    <value>2745</value>   <-- The test should verify this element is always present!
                </IntervalReading>
                <IntervalReading>
                    <cost>2846</cost>
                    <timePeriod>
                        <duration>3600</duration>
                        <start>1333256400</start>
                        <!-- 4/1/2012 5:00:00 AM  -->
                    </timePeriod>
                                          <-- Since there is no <value> entry this should fail!!!
                </IntervalReading>
                <IntervalReading>
                    <cost>2751</cost>
                    <timePeriod>
                        <duration>3600</duration>
                        <start>1333260000</start>
                        <!-- 4/1/2012 6:00:00 AM  -->
                    </timePeriod>
                    <value>917</value>
                </IntervalReading>
                <IntervalReading>
                    <cost>2915</cost>
                    <timePeriod>
                        <duration>3600</duration>
                        <start>1333263600</start>
                        <!-- 4/1/2012 7:00:00 AM  -->
                    </timePeriod>
                    <value>971</value>
                </IntervalReading>
            </IntervalBlock>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I've tried to convert the test to verify the number of  and  elements match, but it always reports they match, although using XMLSpy to run the same count logic separately shows different values.  I suspect the resolution is to change the Context value, but everything I've tried fails to allow the XSL file to compile successfully.

Comment: The code you posted here has errors which do not allow us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a guess because your code has errors.

Your test returns true because there is **at least one** `value` element in the node-set selected by your expression.

If you want to output something when **not all** `IntervalReading` elements have a child `value` element, try something like:

```
<xsl:if test="atom:content/espi:IntervalBlock/espi:IntervalReading[not(espi:value)]" >
```

Note that this path conflicts with your template's match pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but I am dealing with a VBA that converts Excel cell content into Schematron .SCH files and only support entry of the Context (i.e. match-) and Test (i.e., test=) content.  The generated .SCH file is then transformed into a .XSL file using the XMLschematron-report.xsl

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using Relative XPATH addressing since I want to scan for all missing  tags within the  structure.  Here is the logic that I used to solve my issue:

```
    <!--RULE -->
<xsl:template match="//espi:IntervalReading" priority="4000" mode="M10">

        <!--ASSERT -->
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="espi:value" />
<xsl:otherwise>
<assert TestID="EU_FB04_DE_027">
<role></role>
<TestName>IntervalReading value</TestName>
<Report>verify the presence of a valid value</Report>
<diagnostics>for future use</diagnostics>
</assert>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()" mode="M10" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()" priority="-1" mode="M10" />
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" priority="-2" mode="M10">
<xsl:choose>
<!--Housekeeping: SAXON warns if attempting to find the attribute
                           of an attribute-->
<xsl:when test="not(@*)">
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="M10" />
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="M10" />
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```